# Функция slice не работает для document.querySelector. Ошибка .slice is not a function

Tags: javascript, queryselector

Что-то запутался. Почему так? как исправить?

```
var longtext = document.querySelector('.excerpt>p:nth-child(2)');// <p>long long text</p>
var cuttext = longtext.slice(0, 40); // Uncaught TypeError: longtext.slice is not a function
if (cuttext.length < longtext) {
    cuttext += "...";
}
```

Comment: дак что там у вас в `longtext` попало?

Comment: @teran дак я комментарием вывел: `//<p>long long text</p>`

Comment: добавь описание, что именно ты хочешь делать в этой функции.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Используемый метод [`document.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) возвращает **только один** элемент, а не массив.

Поэтому дальнейшая попытка взять первые сорок элементов(?) из одного выглядит странно.

Чтобы получить **коллекцию** элементов необходимо воспользоваться методом [`document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).

Которая возвращает коллекцию подходящих элементов, однако, у возвращаемой коллекции отсутствует метод `slice`, и чтобы его применять нужно либо одолжить его у массива, либо преобразовать полученную коллекцию непосредственно в массив, например с помощью [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)

```
var longtext = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.excerpt>p:nth-child(2)'));
var cuttext = longtext.slice(0,40); //Uncaught TypeError: longtext.slice is not a function
if (cuttext.length < longtext.length) { 
    cuttext+="...";
}
```

---

Однако, судя по названию переменных, можно предположить что работа ожидается с *текстом*, а не html элементами. В этом случае, чтобы получить текст выбранного элемента необходимо было воспользоваться методом [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent), либо если нужно получить текст включая html-теги, [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)

```
var longtext = document.querySelector('.excerpt>p:nth-child(2)').textContent;//long long text
var cuttext = longtext.slice(0,40); //Uncaught TypeError: longtext.slice is not a function
if (cuttext.length < longtext.length) {
    cuttext+="...";
}
```

Comment: @Regent, ага, в первом блоке поправил, потому что там совсем теплое смягким сравнивалось, а во втором пропустил. Хотя странно, почему бы просто не проверить `longtext.length>40`

Comment: Да, приходит в голову такая мысль. По идее, в качестве плюса такого решения можно посчитать то, что `40` не дублируется в коде. Но этот плюс меркнет на фоне взятия подстроки даже тогда, когда это не нужно. Да и `40`, по-хорошему, в любом случае не должно быть магической константой

Comment: Все-таки обрезать html-разметку до 40 символов - такая же глупость, как и применять slice к HTMLElement. Что, к примеру, будет если "разрезать" пополам тэг? Или комментарий? :-) Разумеется, нужно использовать только textContent

Comment: @PavelMayorov, ну, при общей длине менее 40 символов - обрезка до 40 символов ничем не грозит :-)

Answer (score 2):

cuttext в твоем варианте это не массив, а html collection.

переведи html collection в массив, потом сделай слайс

```
var arr = Array.prototype.slice.call( longtext )
var cuttext = arr.slice(0,40);
```

в итоге твой код:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var longtext = document.querySelector('.excerpt>p:nth-child(2)’);
    var arr = Array.prototype.slice.call( longtext );
    var cuttext = arr.slice(0,40);
    if (cuttext.length < longtext) {
        cuttext+="...";
    }
</script>
```

используя ES2015, я обычно делаю так:

```
var arr = [...longtext];
```

Comment: Еще можно `Array.from(longtext)`

Comment: но ведь querySelector возвращает _**один** элемент_ и применив к нему `Array.prototype.slice.call` можно получить только пустой массив.